# Rewriting HQL to convert right join to left join

Tags: hibernate, hql, outer-join

I have the following object model:

```
Account

AccountTransaction
  has many-to-one to Account

PaymentSchedulePayment
  has many-to-one to AccountTransaction

PaymentSchedulePeriod
  has many-to-one to Account
```

And I want some `HQL` that will find me all `PaymentSchedulePeriod` active on the given date and for each one find the latest `PaymentSchedulePayment` linked to the same account.  There may be no payments hence the outer join.

I have a query that works fine:

```
select p.id, a.id, max( pay.accountTransaction.dttm )
from PaymentSchedulePayment pay right join pay.accountTransaction.account a,
PaymentSchedulePeriod p
where p.account = a
and p.fromDttm <= :date and p.toDttm > :date
group by p.id, a.id
```

However from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785002/cross-join-behaviour-sqlserver-2008) I was previously having trouble because of the ordering precedence of the joins which was explained in the accepted answer.  One of the comments was that to avoid issues like this I should use left outer join instead of right but I'm not sure how to rewrite my `HQL` to be of the form

`from Account left join ... PaymentSchedulePayment`

My, possibly incomplete, understanding is that in HQL you can only do outer joins via the object model.

Can anyone suggest how I can rewrite the above as suggested using left rather than right joins?